# Integrate 3CX with Salesforce

Tags: integration

Has anybody integrated 3CX with Salesforce using their standard plug in? If so, is the integration straight forward? And did it perform all the necessary functionality? Also what are the pre requisites? 3CX official website mentioned that 3CX Phone System v14 PRO edition should be available. Is that a paid version? And can I install the plug-in in my dev org for testing purposes?

**Edit: Should the plug in be installed in all the PCs or just one? Suppose there are multiple users, should the plug in be installed in all their systems?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot documentation about that. Please have a look at: http://www.3cx.com/docs/salesforce-crm-integration/

Good luck with that